# prev and Next buttons are appearing next to each other instead of appearing at the edge.

Tags: html, css

Prev and next buttons are appearing next to  each other instead of appearing at the edge of the div , Please help me out to make the buttons appear at the edge .

The below is the html code :

```
    <div id ="moreOption_80322271" class="moreOption">
    <div id="previousButton" class="prevDisabled">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);">&nbsp;</a>
    </div>

    <div id="nextButton" class="nextDisabled">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);">&nbsp;</a>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the CSS styling for the prev and next buttons

```
.moreOption {
    margin-left: 45px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 11.4em;
    width: auto;
    z-index: 1
}
.moreOption .prev {
    margin-right: 7px;
    position: relative
}
.moreOption .next {
    margin-left: 10px;
    position: relative
}
.moreOption .prev a {
    background: url('/ms/img/more_options/inactive_left.png') no-repeat;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 10
}
.moreOption .next a {
    background: url('/ms/img/more_options/inactive_right.png') no-repeat;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 10
}
#popupContent .moreOption {
    top: 11.7em;
    z-index: 999
}
#popupContent .moreOption .prev a {
    background: url('/ms/img/more_options/hover_left.png') no-repeat
}
#popupContent .moreOption .next a {
    background: url('/ms/img/more_options/hover_right.png') no-repeat
}
#popupContent .moreOption .prev a:hover {
    background: url('/ms/img/more_options/mouseover_left.png') no-repeat
}
#popupContent .moreOption .next a:hover {
    background: url('/ms/img/more_options/mouseover_right.png') no-repeat
}
.productContainerCategory .moreOption {
    top: 10.5em
}
.moreOption .prevDisabled {
    margin-right: 7px;
    position: relative
}
.moreOption .nextDisabled {
    margin-left: 10px;
    position: relative
}
.moreOption .prevDisabled a {
    background: url('/ms/img/more_options/inactive_left.png') no-repeat;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 10
}
.moreOption .nextDisabled a {
    background: url('/ms/img/more_options/inactive_right.png') no-repeat;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 10
}
#popupContent .moreOption .prevDisabled a {
    background: url('/ms/img/more_options/inactive_left.png') no-repeat
}
#popupContent .moreOption .nextDisabled a {
    background: url('/ms/img/more_opt[enter image description here][1]ions/inactive_right.png') no-repeat
}
```

Comment: your code is not okeay...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`width: auto;` means that the browser calculates the width.

Since the container have `absolute` position, give a specific size on the `width` on your container or play with `left` and `right` and it's working :

```
.moreOption {
    margin-left: 45px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 11.4em;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[See it here](https://jsfiddle.net/mfqs8vsa/4/)

Comment: Thanks for the little CSS correction @E.Agolli ;) I've edited my fiddle too :)

Comment: NP man @Vincent G. This is a fix to keep the arrows on edges even if the slider has no image but it has an image the arrows would go automatically on edges.

Comment: Right because `width:auto;` is calculated with inner content of the container :)

Comment: @ Vincent G , Thanks for help !! I have changed the left and right properties  as you mentioned and its working now .